# Different characters at end of line when using fscanf in Windows and Linux

Tags: c, linux, windows, newline

When I read with `fscanf`:

```
 nscan = fscanf(input_file, "%30[^,], %d, %lf, %d%c",
                array[i].epwnymo, &array[i].ypolipo,
                &array[i].epitokio, &array[i].meromhnia, &termch);
```

`termch` should be `\n`, but in Linux, I get `\r` which makes my program give the wrong result. I have read somewhere that windows `\n` is `\r\n` but, why do I get `\r` in Linux?

Comment: Note: space before `"%d"`, `"%lf"` serves no purpose here.  OTOH a space before `","` and  `"%30[^,]` is useful.  --> `" %30[^,],%d ,%lf ,%d%c",`

Answer (score 7):

This is technically not a C problem, since you would notice the same thing in all programming languages.

If you've copied the file straight from Windows to Linux without transforming newlines (FTP gives you an option of doing this by selecting TEXT or ASCII transfer mode), it would make sense that your Linux program sees `'\r'` characters; these would normally be translated as part of a `"\r\n"` sequence in Windows, but Linux performs no such translation automatically.

I recommend, when you're copying text files from Windows to Linux, that you run `dos2unix` to convert these text files (unless you're using an FTP client that performs this conversion for you)... and similarly, when you're copying text files from Linux to Windows, you should probably use `unix2dos` (again, except for the FTP scenario).

Comment: well thing is that I am doing home assignments for university, and probably they are written in windows, and in this exercise the 2 files are standard, which means i have to take them as windows files.  By doing what you suggest, would it work? or taking the files and rewrite them using notepad++ on linux?

Comment: @GPwoopzi Are you trying to say that you're not allowed to change the files?

Comment: i tried to do so with dos2unix but didn't work, so i just copied the content of the file and pasted it in a new one made on linux

Comment: I suggest reading the [dos2unix man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix) if you have problems using it...

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you can deal with differing conventions for `newline` endings by first reading to a string, removing any `newline` chars, and then scanning the string, without any `newline` test.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//...

char input[100];
if (fgets(input, sizeof input, input_file) != NULL) {
    input [ strcspn(input, "\r\n") ] = 0;              // remove trailing newline etc
    nscan = sscanf(input, "%30[^,], %d, %lf, %d",
        array[i].epwnymo, &array[i].ypolipo, &array[i].epitokio, &array[i].meromhnia);    
}
```

This works in MSVC for a file containing lines ending with `\r` and `\n` and `\r\n`, I can't try it with Linux.

Comment: Yes, best way to handle text files with variant line endings.

Comment: But since you are now using `sscanf` to extract the fields, there is no need to even remove the `newline`.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend a new approach.  When code needs to read a *line* of text, start with `fgets()`.

The problem encountered because 1) various OS use different line endings such as  `\n` `\r\n` and `\r` 2) Code is working with text files using the alternate line endings and 3) OP's code is not attempting to *read a line*.

The following will accept and consume candidate line ending in 5 places - not only at the end.

```
         vv  vv   vv  v
"%30[^,], %d, %lf, %d%c"
```

The problem with `"%c"` is that it will accept only 1 character of the 2 character line ending `\r\n`.  This is not a problem when code is compiled where text files are expected to end with `\r\n` as since the stream is in text mode, the `\r\n` is converted to `\n`.  Yet if code is compiled on a system that expects only 1 end-of-line character, a `\r\n` will remain as 2 characters.

The classic approach is to use a `" "` in the `fscanf()` to consume these various white-spaces.

```
" %30[^,], %d, %lf, %d"
"%30[^,], %d, %lf, %d "
```

---

IMO, the best first step in reading a *line* of text is to use `fgets()`, *then* parse.

```
//                        [],sp %d ,sp    %lf    ,sp %d /r/n/0
#define LINE_EXPECT_MAX (30+1+1+20+1+1+(309+1+6)+1+1+20+2+1)
char buf[LINE_EXPECT_MAX];

if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, input_file) == NULL) return EOF;
```

Using `" %n"` to detect complete scan and look for trailing extra non-white-space text is easy:

```
int n = 0;    
sscanf(buf, "%30[^,], %d, %lf, %d %n",
    array[i].epwnymo, &array[i].ypolipo, &array[i].epitokio, &array[i].meromhnia, &n);
if (n == 0) Handle_Incomplete_Scan();
if (buf[n] != '\0') Handle_Unxpected_Text();
```

---

Lastly, a space before `"%d"` and `"%lf"` serves little purpose as those specifier will consume leading white-space even without the leading space.  Yes a space before the `","`, will pass spaces after the number and before the comma.

```
" %30[^,],%d ,%lf ,%d %n"
```